# Meaning of instruction in Drwatson FAULT file

Tags: assembly, fault, drwatson

I have the following Dr Watson file log:

What's the meaning of?

```
 FAULT ->301af532 807e010a         cmp     byte ptr [esi+0x1],0xa  ds:0023:784fb000=??
```

I read in another post info about eip=301af532, instruction that failed..

```
*----> State Dump for Thread Id 0x768 <----*

eax=00000000 ebx=784fb000 ecx=0366ffdc edx=7727539c esi=784fafff edi=00000001
eip=301af532 esp=0366fe8c ebp=0366febc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246

function: lvrt!TDStandardize
        301af51c 4d               dec     ebp
        301af51d 1450             adc     al,0x50
        301af51f 51               push    ecx
        301af520 52               push    edx
        301af521 e87adbffff       call    lvrt!TDStandardize+0xcc70 (301ad0a0)
        301af526 83c420           add     esp,0x20
        301af529 3bf3             cmp     esi,ebx
        301af52b 730c             jnb     lvrt!TDStandardize+0xf109 (301af539)
        301af52d 803e0d           cmp     byte ptr [esi],0xd
        301af530 7507             jnz     lvrt!TDStandardize+0xf109 (301af539)
FAULT ->301af532 807e010a         cmp     byte ptr [esi+0x1],0xa  ds:0023:784fb000=??
        301af536 7501             jnz     lvrt!TDStandardize+0xf109 (301af539)
        301af538 46               inc     esi
        301af539 8b45e8           mov     eax,[ebp-0x18]
        301af53c 46               inc     esi
        301af53d 663d3000         cmp     ax,0x30
        301af541 7507             jnz     lvrt!TDStandardize+0xf11a (301af54a)
        301af543 b804000000       mov     eax,0x4
        301af548 eb0c             jmp     lvrt!TDStandardize+0xf126 (301af556)
        301af54a 0fbfc0           movsx   eax,ax
        301af54d 50               push    eax
```

Comment: Well, it's a compare of the byte at 0x784fb000 (esi+1) to the value 0xa, but the address is invalid - hinted at by the question marks towards the end of the faulting instruction disassembly. It's not obvious from what you show how esi got the incorrect value.

Comment: Ok, thanks..I'm looking at user.dmp finding this information: MODULE_NAME: lvrt FAULTING_MODULE: 7c900000 ntdll FOLLOWUP_IP: lvrt!TDStandardize+f102 301af532 807e010a cmp byte ptr [esi+1],0Ah I think 0Ah should be a buffered array from standard input. It's right or I should consider 0Ah=0xa??